# Stateful LSTM input shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am doing a project that handling long sequence multiclass classification.
Here is the organization of my data 
[google colab snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHLJC.png)
I've segmented the whole sequence into 60 subsequences, each contains 250 samples.
The y_train as below.

```
y_train = []
for i in range(len(resampled_data)):
  y_train.append(1)
y_train_array = np.array(y_train)
one_hot_y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(1,num_classes=4)
print("y_train")
print(len(one_hot_y_train))
y_train = np.array([one_hot_y_train]*60)
print(np.shape(y_train))
print(y_train)
```

I have 4 classes for classfication and for this sequence was labeled as '1'(class 1)

And the model defined as below.

```
#start constructing  stateful LSTM  model
model = Sequential()       
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(250,batch_input_shape=(60,250,1), 
activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,stateful=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250,shuffle=False)
```

But when training the model, there's an error that I cannot fully understand.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_23 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60, 4)
```

I was wondering why this happened and how to fix it, is something wrong with my input shape or my concepts were errors?
Ps. In this case, I'm just using only a sequence for testing my model if it could run without errors, and for the next step, I will use a loop to train all the data! Right now I'm stuck on this problem. If somebody could guide me, I would highly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `return_sequences=True` in

`model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(250,batch_input_shape=(60,250,1), 
activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,stateful=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2))`

It returns a 3 dimensional tensor of shape `[batch_size, time_step, hidden_dim]`

Now if you want to use a dense layer for such time-series data, you need to use the [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) in Keras the following way,

`model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4,activation='softmax')))`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! After couple days,I think I’ve addressed the issues by the method you provided! Thanks for your suggestions and support!